# Context.pop not been called when dialog is active

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a timer that once completed, the user is moved away from the screen through:

```
context.pop
```

Problem is when `showExitPopup` is active, `context.pop` is not called called, hence the user still remains on the screen even after the time has elapsed

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
if(_controller!.isCompleted){
  context.pop(); ==> this is not called when the dialog is open
  //call submit test function
 }
}
```

This is the dialog..

```
Future<bool> showExitPopup(String title, String message, String action) async {
return await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text(title),
    content: Text(message),
    actions:[
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
        //return false when click on "NO"
        child:const Text('No, continue test'),
      ),

      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
        //return true when click on "Yes"
        child: Text(action)
       ),
    ],
  ),
 )??false; //if showDialog had returned null, then return false
}
```

Comment: if u wanna navigate to another page, add Navigator.pop(context) 2 times in ElevateButton( onPressed: (){ //pop 2 times here })

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to call setState((){}) after context.pop. Maybe the page is not updating.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
if(_controller!.isCompleted){
  context.pop(); ==> this is not called when the dialog is open
  //call submit test function
  setState((){});
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work.